# last integer in a string in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list containing integer or string-integer
like this

```
   TagNo      FTerminal
    1000         1
    1000         5
    1000         2S6
```

how can i get the result like this

```
   TagNo      FTerminal
    1000         1
                 5
                 6
```

I have this , but definately it gives me error on 2s6.
how can i change it to cover all?

```
 var terminalList = sourceLists.Where(t => t.TagNo == tagList)
                               .Where(t=>t.FromTerminal.Length>0)
                               .Select(t => int.Parse(t.FromTerminal))
                               .OrderBy(t=>t)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: How `2S6` should be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `int.Parse` in your LINQ statement, you need to write your own function.

Something like this:

```
int parseTerminal(string input) {
    int result = -1;
    if (!int.TryParse(input, out result)) {
        result = -99;
    }
    return result;
}
```

That would make your LINQ to

```
var terminalList = sourceLists
               .Where( t => t.TagNo == tagList && t.FromTerminal.Length > 0 )
               .Select( t => parseTerminak(t.FromTerminal) )
               .OrderBy( t=>t )
               .ToList();
```

Result:

```
TagNo      FTerminal
1000       -99
           1
           5
```

You need to handle the special case where FromTerminal is not a number yourself.

A naive implementation of the requirement one could think of is something like this:

```
int parseTerminal(string input) {
    int result = -1;
    if (!int.TryParse(input, out result)) {
        var temporaryString = string.Empty;
        var lastInt = -1;

        input.ToList().ForEach( aChar => {
            if ( aChar >= '0' && aChar <= '9' ) {
                temporaryString += aChar;
            }  else {
                if ( temporaryString.Length >= 0 ) {
                    int.TryParse( temporaryString, out lastInt );
                    temporaryString = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        } );
        if ( temporaryString.Length >= 0 ) {
            if (!int.TryParse( temporaryString, out lastInt )) {
                lastInt = -98;
            }
        }
        result = lastInt;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note: I would not consider this production ready and you should think about edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your data structure I have written a code using some system types.

```
var tuples = new List<Tuple<int, string>>
                 {
                     new Tuple<int, string>(1000, "1"),
                     new Tuple<int, string>(1000, "5"),
                     new Tuple<int, string>(1000,"2s6")
                 };
var enumerable = tuples.GroupBy(t => t.Item1).
    Select(g => new Tuple<int, List<int>>(g.Key, g.Select(e => int.Parse(Regex.Match(e.Item2, @"(?<=(\D|^))\d+(?=\D*$)").Value)).ToList()));
```

Comment: His last value is `2s6` not `256` this is why the parser is having trouble with it.

Comment: Actually I am not parsing. Just taking the last value which might also cause give wrong output if the last value is non-numeric.

Comment: @Muctadir He tries to select int values and the last string 2S6 (note the 's') is not convertable to int with int.Parse

Comment: Refined the answer using Regex.

Answer (score 0):

if last symbol always is int you may change your code like this

```
var terminalList = sourceLists.Where(t => t.TagNo == tagList)
                           .Where(t=>t.FromTerminal.Length>0)
                           .Select(t => int.Parse(t.FromTerminal.Last()))
                           .OrderBy(t=>t)
                           .ToList();
```

**UPDATE**
if last not only one numer that can use regex like this

```
var terminalList = sourceLists.Where(t => t.TagNo == tagList)
                           .Where(t=>t.FromTerminal.Length>0)
                           .Select(t => int.Parse(Regex.Match(t.FromTerminal, @"(\d+)$").Groups[1].Value))
                           .OrderBy(t=>t)
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you try to handle the **string** '2S6' as an **integer**, using `int.Parse`. This would naturally cause an exception.

I would suggest following another approach, using regular expressions. I think regular expressions are better solution since the data you ask come **after string manipulation** of the **already retrieved query** results.

Using regular expressions to do this kind of staff, would make it also easier for you to maintain in the future. Think of the case, that in a week you don't want to retrieve the last digit of the string, but the second digit of the string.

You can use [this online regular expression tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) to test your regular expression. I suppose the regular expression `\d(?!.*\d)` would be a good choice, since it returns the last digit.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good guide in using regular expressions in .NET, including examples.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

I am quiet confused what do you wants ... as your picture says you wants the combination of **TagNO** and **FTerminal** and in the other hand your query says you wants only FTerminals in certain order ..

Now if you wants the **first one** then

```
void Abc(int tagList)
{
    var sourceLists = new List<Demo>
    {
        new Demo { FTerminal = "200", TagNo = 1000 },
        new Demo { FTerminal = "300", TagNo = 1000 },
        new Demo { FTerminal = "400", TagNo = 1000 }
    };

    var terminalList = sourceLists
        .Where(t => t.TagNo == tagList && t.FTerminal.Length > 0)
        .OrderBy(i=>i.FTerminal).GroupBy(i=>i.TagNo);                                                               
}
```

And the **second one**

```
void Abc(int tagList)
{

    var sourceLists = new List<Demo>
        {
          new Demo { FTerminal = "200", TagNo = 1000 },
          new Demo { FTerminal = "300", TagNo = 1000 },
          new Demo { FTerminal = "400", TagNo = 1000 }
        };

    var terminalList = 
        from Demo d in sourceLists
            where d.TagNo == tagList
            let number = int.Parse(d.FTerminal)
            orderby number ascending
            select number).ToList();
}
```

But till if you did not get the your desired answer then please knock!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... instead of jumping through hoops, just use IsInt ... problem solved ...
:)

```
var terminalList = sourceLists.Where(t => t.TagNo == tagList)
                           .Where(t=>t.FromTerminal.Length>0)
                           .Where(t => t.FromTerminal.IsInt() )
                           .Select(t => int.Parse(t.FromTerminal))
                           .OrderBy(t=>t)
                           .ToList();
```

(So, just added this condition `.Where(t => t.FromTerminal.IsInt() )` to your selection process)

Comment: This means dropping a valid value instead of handling it. This might be OK, but also might be a drawback

Comment: True, but he didn't specified what should happen ... :) If he wants it, he can do exactly the same with the opposite, and handle all the rubbish data :)